# Konva Find name of the Group that a shape is within

Tags: konvajs

[Example demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Collision_Detection.html#page-title)

Within the 'dragmove' event listener, is there a way to return the name (in this example the name is group created within the createShape function) of the group that the shapes are added to at the start?

Ultimate need for this is to be able to identify the groups within a collision detection and then use the .moveTo function to combine them. I can use the .moveTo statically but it would be better to have it dynamic for future shapes being added.

I've searched the API but can't find a way to return the group name that a shape is linked with

Answer (score 0):

Each Konva Node object has a name() function which returns the name of the node.

Being part of a group means being a child of a node. So the group is the parent of your node. To get a parent element you can use the getParent() function.

Therefore `node.getParent().name()` should do the job.

I help I understood your question correctly. If not feel free to comment.